# how to escape % at cmd setx?

Tags: window, cmd

I'm trying to set var by cmd script, but got some problem,

```
setx /M JAVA_HOME "D:\Tool\JDK"
setx /M PATH "%PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;D:\TZProfile\!!!QuickLink\"
```

I want to add %JAVA_HOME%\bin to PATH, no "D:\Tool\JDK"

Comment: It is very doubtful that `%JAVA_HOME%` will be automatically evaluated when searching for a file called by its name only. Anyway, @manojlds has correctly answered your question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On commandline use `^` to escape, like so

```
^%JAVA_HOME^%
```

In batch file, use `%` to escape, like so

```
%%JAVA_HOME%%
```

Comment: Exact problem, same solution: Tks!

Comment: The `%%` in a batch file worked for me.  Coworker and I could never get command line using `^` to work.